# Why are my upper-case Greek letters italic by default?

Tags: math-mode, packages, greek, incompatibility, italic

While reading my document I have noticed that the upper-case Greek letters that appear on it are written in italic. However, I don't know why this is happening, and I would like to revert this situation.

Here is a minimal working example in which I include all the packages that appear on the preambles of my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
        \rel@kern{0.8}%
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
        \rel@kern{-0.2}%
    }%
    \macc@depth\@ne
    \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
    \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
    \macc@set@skewchar\relax
    \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fixmath} % for \mathbold
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\bshft
\bshft=.18pt\relax
\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
            \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
            \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}

\usepackage{tikz} % Para pictures
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows} %decoracion en tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{optics}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\newcommand{\longsquiggly}{\xymatrix{{}\ar@{~>}[r]&{}}}

\renewenvironment{proof}%
{\noindent{\em Demostración. }\nopagebreak}%
{\hfill\linebreak[2]\hspace*{\fill}$\Box$\\[6pt]}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
    <9-10> MnSymbolC9
    <10-12> MnSymbolC10
    <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intprod}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{'270}

\begin{document}
$\Omega$
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the behavior on TeX Live 2020. So it’s one of your other packages, probably changing the math font to OML encoding.

Comment: @campa I have added a MWE to my question.

Comment: @Davislor It has to be another package that I dind't include. I have added all of them to my question.

Comment: @shekura beat me to it: `fixmath` changes to ISO style, in which upright Greek letters are slanted.

Comment: Your comment says that you wanted it for `\mathbold`, but you can use `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` without `fixmath`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused be `\usepackage{fixmath}`, once you comment that line, the omega is upright.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the documentation, `fixmath` says, “This package ensures that uppercase Greek be typeset in italic style.”

Comment: Maybe I should have called it a 'feature' rather than an 'issue' then.